# Extended authorization when group can be disabled

Tags: c#, .net-core, authorization, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-middleware

I am writing a .net core 3.1 API application and have authorization implemented in the app. It is done via IPolicyRequirement and AuthorizationHandler.

```
services.AddAuthorizationCore(options =>
                              {
                                  AddPolicy(options, new UserRequirement());
                              });

services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, UserHandler>();
```

and required controllers are decorated with `Authorize` attribute.

```
    [ApiController]
    [Authorize(Policy = UserRequirement.Policy)]
    [Route("/api/[controller]")]
    public class TeamDetailsController : ControllerBase
    {
        ...
    }
```

It all works fine and restricts access to controller calls where specified.

Now I need to restrict access based on if team to which account belongs is enabled. So, if the team is disabled, people can login, but cannot access most end points.

They still should be able to access some end points as otherwise they would not be able to make actions, specified by business, that would allow to re-enable the team. Not any role is going to be allowed to call that end points - only specified by Authorize policy.

I also can do it via policy requirements, but now I want a specific error message with 403, so, the API callers can differ role-based 403 from the team-disabled 403. I think 403 is ideal code for both cases as access is forbidden in both cases to specified end points, just for role-unrelated reasons in some cases.

So, to sum up, I need to return 403 with a message from policy requirement, something like:

```
public class UserHandler : AuthorizationHandler<UserRequirement>
{
    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
                                                         UserRequirement requirement)
    {
        var authenticatedUser = GetUserFromClaims();
        if (!await TeamIsEnabled(authenticatedUser))
        {
            context.Resource.Result = new JsonResult("Custom message");
            return;
        }

        if (!await RoleIsAllowed())
            return;

        context.Succeed(requirement);
    }
}
```

The code above does not work as content.Resource is of `RouteEndpoint` type and does not have Result property to send.

My questions are:

- Is my approach using policy requirement to disable access to resources based on authorization policy requirements correct in terms of industry standard?
- If so, how can I return a message for team-disabled 403?
- If 403 should not be returned when team is disabled, what code should it be? I do not want to return 409 Conflict as it is used for db concurrency exception.

Should I use middleware and IAsyncResultFilter? I can use it but I thought I should ask the community if I could get away with

Thank you.

Comment: I think you should use Middleware,so that you can return 403.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in the end I split these into 2 bits:

- a filter that implements IAsyncAuthorizationFilter to handle the group on/off, returns 400 with error details as I could not make the filter to return 403 with message.
- a handler that implements AuthorizationHandler to restrict access to a specific user and requirements implement IPolicyRequirement.

in `startup.cs` we have:

```
services.AddControllers(opt =>
{
 ...
 opt.Filters.Add<GroupIsEnabledFilter>();
 ...
});

services.AddAuthorizationCore(options =>
{
 AddPolicy(options, new MaintainerRequirement());
 AddPolicy(options, new SuperUserRequirement());
})
...
;

services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, MaintainerHandler>();
services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, SuperUserHandler>();
```

the filter template could be like this:

```
public class GroupIsEnabledFilter : IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
{
  public GroupIsEnabledFilter(...)
  {
      ...
      //inject your dependencies here
      ...
  }
  
  public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
  {
    if (AllowsDisabledGroup(context)) //use context.ActionDescriptor.EndpointMetadata to get endpoint details
        return;
  
    var group = _authService.GetGroupId();
    if (await GroupIsActive(group))
        return;
  
    var problemDetails = new ProblemDetails
    {
    ...
    };
  
    context.Result = new ObjectResult(problemDetails)
    {
        ContentTypes = new MediaTypeCollection { new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json") },
        StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest
    };
  }
}
```